# htaccess url rewriting 2 get values

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using **PHP 7.2** URL Rewrite Rules. i am making   2 links first link is "**category.php?inventory_id=**" and second links "**show-subcategories.php?cat_id**" but the result is always the first link is working missing code, please help ...

**I have need URL**

```
www.example.com/product-list-nokia-1 // category url
www.example.com/category/product-list-nokia-n72-3 // subcategory url
www.example.com/category/subcategory/product-list-nokia-n72-3 // subcategory url
```

**Current URL**

```
https://www.example.com/show-subcategories.php?cat_id=1
https://www.example.com/show-childcategories.php?sub_cat_id=1
https://www.example.com/search-result.php?p_id=1
```

**The htaccess code here...**

**error rule please check it's now**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (\d+)$ category.php?inventory_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule category/(\d+)$ show-subcategories.php?cat_id=$1 [L]//error part rule is not working
```

Comment: You are trying to match the exact same pattern in both your rules here, which makes no sense.

Comment: please correction this code and show me please

Comment: You need to correct your requirement/specification first. You are currently looking for the same pattern in both of those rules - which means it will always take the first one. The server has no way of knowing at this point, whether for example `123` is supposed to be the id of a category, or a sub-category. So you either need to use _different_ URL patterns for both, so that this becomes discernible at this point; or you use just _one_ RewriteRule to pass this on to _one_ PHP script, and then make the distinction whether this is a category or a sub-category id inside of that script.

Comment: RewriteRule (\d+)$ show-subcategories.php?cat_id=$1 [L] result

Comment: this type "https://www.proyellowpage.com/category/product-list-1"

Comment: `(\d+)$` matches _any_ URL path that ends with digits - so it matches `category/product-list-1` as well. So the first rule takes effect already, and your second rule matching `category/(\d+)$` doesn’t come into play any more. Reverse the order of these rules.

Comment: please share edit code sir

Comment: I have need URL ( www.example.com/product-list-nokia-1 // category url )
( www.example.com/category/product-list-nokia-n72-3 // subcategory url )

Comment: ok sorry sir i am waiting

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: yes sir but the result is nothing so, please  help...